# python itertools round robin explaintation

Tags: python, iterator

I came across this code snippet for round robin in https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html, but I couldn't understand how the last line `nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))` removes the exhausted generator from nexts iterator. To my understanding, this removes the last one from input but shouldn't we remove the first one, i.e. the current one that throws this exception?

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    """Yields an item from each iterable, alternating between them.

        >>> list(roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF'))
        ['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'C']

    This function produces the same output as :func:`interleave_longest`, but
    may perform better for some inputs (in particular when the number of
    iterables is small).

    """
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    if PY2:
        nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    else:
        nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll break it up for you, step by step:

```
>>> list(roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF'))


pending = 3  # len(('ABC', 'D', 'EF'))

# nexts roughly equivalent to:
['ABC', 'D', 'EF', 'ABC', 'D', 'EF', 'ABC', ...]

***

# the following get yielded 
'A' from 'ABC' # nexts: ['D' , 'EF', 'BC', 'D' , 'EF', ...]
'D' from 'D'   # nexts: ['EF', 'BC', ''  , 'EF', 'BC', ...]
'E' from 'EF'  # nexts: ['BC', ''  , 'F' , 'BC', ''  , ...]
'B' from 'BC'  # nexts: [''  , 'F' , 'C' , ''  , 'F' , ...]

# StopIteration was raised by what used to be "B"
SI from ''  # nexts:  ['F', 'C', '', 'F', 'C', '', 'F', ...]
#                                 ^ index 2 (`pending`[see the following line])

# pending -= 1
pending = 2

# when islice() is used with one argument, it defaults to the "stop" index
# so islice() returns ['F', 'C']
# and cycle() converts it to ['F', 'C', 'F', 'C', ...]

pending = 2
nexts: ['F', 'C', 'F', 'C', ...]

# Go back to *** and continue until pending = 0
```

And that's how the last line removes the exhausted iterable.

---

Main idea:

```
for next in nexts:
    yield next()
```

Even if `StopIteration` is raised, the exhausted iterable had already been used from `nexts`.

So instead of the exhausted iterable remaining as the first item in `nexts`:

```
nexts = ['', 'F', 'C', '', 'F', 'C', '', 'F', ...]
```

The first item of `nexts` is actually the next item:

```
nexts = ['F', 'C', '', 'F', 'C', '', 'F', ...]
```

Comment: Got it, in fact we have already consume the SI when it throws the exception, so to remove it we need remove it from the end. Great explantation!

Answer (score 1):

Because `cycle()` creates an infinite iterator, you are not always slicing from the "beginning" of `iterables` when `islice()` is used in the final line.  To simplify a bit, `nexts` as it is originally defined will "loop back" to the beginning of `iterables`:

```
try:
    for next in nexts:
        print(next())
except StopIteration:
    print('decrementing...')
A
D
E
B
decrementing...
```

The goal at this point is to remove the exhausted iterator that was formed from `'D'`.  The key is that you're now "at" `'EF'`, with the iterator that was formed from `'ABC'` being next in line, so `islice(nexts, pending)` will cycle from `'EF'` to `'ABC'`.

Here is a related example:

```
x = cycle('abcd')
#          ^  |
#          |__|

for _ in range(3):
    x.__next__()

list(islice(x, 2))
# ['d', 'a']
```